# Group algebra functor preserves colimits

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, group-rings

Consider a commutative unital ring $R$ and the group algebra functor
$$R[-]:\bf{Grp}\rightarrow {Alg}_R$$
which has the group of units functor 
$$(-)^\ast:\bf{Alg}_R\rightarrow \bf{Grp}$$
as right-adjoint. Hence it preserves colimits, in particular we should have
$$R[G\ast H]\cong R[G]\otimes_R R[H]$$
where $G\ast H$ denotes the free product (which is the coproduct) of groups. However apparently the equality $$R[G\times H]\cong R[G]\otimes_R R[H]$$ holds. So if I am not mistaken we have
$$R[G\ast H]\cong R[G\times H]$$
for any two groups $G$ and $H$. Am I correct? It does not seem right to me. Also, is there a way to derive the identity $R[G\times H]\cong R[G]\otimes_R R[H]$ from abstract nonsense?

Comment: That doesn't seem right to me either. I think the problem is that the tensor product is the coproduct in the category of *commutative* algebras, but the group algebra isn't commutative if the group isn't abelian.

Comment: Ah, you're right, and in the Abelian case the equality $R[G\times H]\cong R[G]\otimes_R R[H]$ then follows as $G\otimes H=G\oplus H$ in that case.

Comment: @Arnaud.D: how does one show that the tensor product is the coproduct in $CAlg$? Is there a quick way of demonstrating this?

Comment: @Arnaud.D: I'm interested because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630551/how-does-one-phrase-the-construction-of-the-tensor-product-categorically?noredirect=1#comment5439477_2630551) question I asked on reframing the tensor product as a universal morphism. Now, I know how to frame the categorical product as a terminal morphism, and so coproducts will be initial. So, reframing tensor products as a coproduct should solve my problem.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I would just prove that the tensor product satisfies the universal property of a coproduct, which is not too hard.

Comment: @asdq: I'm sorry about the last comment. My mistake and misunderstanding. Thanks for the tip, however the preamble to my question does show the standard universal property of the tensor product, but I was interested in formulating this as a universal morphism. I've found the solution as listed in the answer to the question, if you're interested.

Comment: @asdq: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1676379) there is a proof of that isomorphism by abstract nonsense.